# Read CSV, with date filtering and resampling

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the following function to read multiple CSV files into pandas dataframes. Depending on the use case, the user can pass optional resampling (frequency and method) and/or a date range (start/end). For both options I'd like to check if both keywords were given and raise errors if not.

My issue is that reading the CSV files can potentially take quite a bit of time and it's quite frustrating to get the value error 5 minutes after you've called the function. I could duplicate the `if` statements at the top of the function. However I'd like to know if there is a more readable way or a best practice that avoids having the same `if`/`else` statements multiple times.

```
def file_loader(filep,freq:str = None, method: str =None ,d_debut: str =None,d_fin: str =None):
    df= pd.read_csv(filep,\
            index_col=0,infer_datetime_format=True,parse_dates=[0],\
            header=0,names=['date',filep.split('.')[0]])\
            .sort_index()
    if d_debut is not None:
        if d_fin is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide an end timestamp!")
        else:
            df=df.loc[ (df.index >= d_debut) & (df.index <= d_fin)]
        
    if freq is not None:
        if method is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a resampling method for the given frequency eg. 'last' ,'mean'")
        else:
            ## getattr sert à appeler ...resample(freq).last() etc avec les kwargs en string ex: freq='1D' et method ='mean'
            df= getattr(df.resample(freq), method)()

    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal to do the parameter checking first:

```
def file_loader(filep, freq: str = None, method: str = None,
                d_debut: str = None, d_fin: str = None):
    if d_debut is not None and d_fin is None:
        raise ValueError("Please provide an end timestamp!")
    if freq is not None and method is None:
        raise ValueError("Please provide a resampling method for the given frequency e.g. 'last' ,'mean'")
```

You might prefer to check that `d_fin` and `d_debut` are either both provided or both defaulted, rather than allowing `d_fin` without `d_debut` as at present:

```
    if (d_debut is None) != (d_fin is None):
        raise ValueError("Please provide both start and end timestamps!")
```

Then after loading, the conditionals are simple:

```
    if d_debut is not None:
        assert(d_fin is not None)  # would have thrown earlier
        df = df.loc[df.index >= d_debut and df.index <= d_fin]
        
    if freq is not None:
        assert(method is not None)  # would have thrown earlier
        df = getattr(df.resample(freq), method)()
```

The assertions are there to document something we know to be true. You could omit them safely, but they do aid understanding.

---

It may make sense to provide a useful default `method` rather than None.  Similarly, could the `df.index >= d_debut and df.index <= d_fin` test be adapted to be happy with one or the other cutoff missing?  For example:

```
    if d_debut is not None or d_fin is not None:
        df = df.loc[(d_debut is None or df.index >= d_debut) and 
                    (d_fin is None or df.index <= d_fin)]
```

Then we wouldn't need the parameter checks at all.

---

Code style - please take more care with whitespace (consult PEP-8) for maximum readability.  Lots of this code seems unnecessarily bunched-up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd rather the function force the user to understand exactly what data he is getting, hence the strict checks. I don't understand why you have assert statements. As you've commented, errors would have been raised at the top. And my bad for the styling.

Comment: The asserts are there to document something we know to be true.  You could omit them safely, but they do aid understanding.